# R: how to specify resolution/quality in animate package

Tags: r, animation

The `animate` package in `R` has a function `saveVideo` that saves images as a video format.

From the [documentation:](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/animation/versions/2.6/topics/saveVideo)

```
saveVideo(expr, video.name = "animation.mp4", img.name = "Rplot", 
    ffmpeg = ani.options("ffmpeg"), other.opts = if (grepl("[.]mp4$", 
        video.name)) "-pix_fmt yuv420p", ...)
```

and it seems the 'bit-rate' needs to be specified under `other-opts`.

I don't fully understand what `bit-rate` means here, and how it is supposed to be specified other than just trial and error, and how it relates to the resolution of the output.

In `R`, we also have the function `png()` which saves images, where one can specify `width`, `height`, and `res`. I'd like to do something similar here. Is there a guideline for how to choose bit-rate so that I get the desired size and quality for the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [documentation page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/animation/versions/2.6/topics/ani.options) for `ani.options`?
Among those that seem to answer your are `ani.width, ani.height`
, and `ani.res`to manually adjust the width, height, and resolution of your animation.